# Is there an analytic definition of reflection?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider some real function $f$. Then its *reflection about the y-axis* is defined as the function $g$ satisfying $g(x) = f(-x)$; its *reflection about the x-axis* is defined similarly as the function $h$ satisfying $h(x) = -f(x)$. These are the analytic (rather than graphical) definitions of reflection.

Do there exist general analytic definitions for reflections about arbitrary lines, rather than just the y-axis or x-axis? Or, indeed, curves even?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

First, a quick note: once we start talking about general reflections, we probably want to talk about reflecting individual *points*, or general *curves*, rather than functions; this is because if you reflect (the graph of) a function across a line which is not vertical or horizontal, you might not get a function back - the new graph may fail the vertical line test. It's a good exercise to try and figure out why vertical and horizontal lines are special in this respect . . .

To reflect a point $(m, n)$ across a line $L$ given by $y=ax+b$, we first draw the line of slope $-{1\over a}$ through $(m, n)$ (this line is perpendicular to $L$ - do you see why?). The equation of this line is $$y=-{1\over a}x+({m\over a}+n).$$

Next, we find where this line intersects $L$. After algebra, we get $$x={{m}+an-ab\over a^2+1},$$ and a similarly nasty expression for $y$; call these values $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively.

The point is that $\mu$ is halfway between $m$ and the $x$-coordinate of the reflection of $(m, n)$ across $L$, and similarly for $\nu$ (why?); so to finish up, the coordinates of $(m, n)$ reflected across $L$ are $$(2\mu-m, 2\nu-n).$$

(Note that since we assume $L$ is not horizontal, the divisions by $a$ are non-problematic; and since we assume $L$ is not vertical, it is in fact the graph of a linear function.)

---

For reflection across a curve, this is a bit weirder; there are multiple different reasonable definitions for what this might be. For one particular case - reflection across a circle - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. If I insist on using functions, is it fine to restrict them such that we only work with bijections?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 No - for instance, if we reflect the graph of the function $f(x)={1\over \sqrt{3}}x$ across the line $y=\sqrt{3}x$, we get the line $x=0$ which is not a function, even though $f$ was bijective.